# How to use VMware vCloud solely from Google Chrome (including remote console plug-in)

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

Is there any way/workaround to use vCloud remote console plug-in, also with a newer version of Google Chrome?

I've learned that remote console plug-in is not working anymore for Google Chrome for some while:
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2088744

The error I'm getting is that the VMRC plug-in is not installed, although it has been for sure installed and works when using solely on IE.

After this, I've searched for a workaround, so that I could still rely solely on Chrome, including vCloud. 
I have tried out the following:

- found a Chrome plug-in called [ietab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd), with which I've succeeded to start at least the vApp management view
- tried to launch/pop-up the remote console plug-in in a new IE window/instance, from vApp management view (which is opened through ietab plug-in from Google Chrome)
- installed different versions of IE and Chrome => no success
- tried out different compatibility mode settings of IE => no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging, I've found a way to make it work.

Following steps were necessary, in my case:

1. Add to Google Chrome the IE Tab plug-in, from Chrome Web Store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd
2. Open plug-in through shortcut button from the left of the adress bar and download+install the necessary executable
3. Press again the plug-in shortcut button and under the normal address bar, and on the left of the new lower address bar, press the button with tools-icon
4. In the "General Option" section, check the first 3 checkboxes (*Enable Auto URLs*, *Open pop-up windows with Chrome* and *Use a full Window when displaying pop-ups*)
   **If you still want to pop-up the orignal IE-based Remote console window from Chrome, leave "Open pop-up windows with Chrome" unchecked**
5. In the "Auto URLs" section, add the vCloud-URL with asterix-wildcard at the end (for example https://vcloud.your-domain.com/*). **In the same section, you may add other IE-URLs like Sharepoint-link (to be able to checking-out documents like under IE), or other IE-only URLs (see the examples in the picture).**
6. In the "IE Compatibility Mode" section, select "IE 9 Forced Standards Mode"
7. Open the vCloud-URL and it should open under Chrome using IEs Tridend-engine (If it does not open automatically using the plug-in, press the plug-in shortcut button left of the normal address bar)
8. Also the Remote Console plug-in should pop-ul in a new Chrome-window, including support for tabbed browsing
9. As already said, if you preffer, it is possible to pop-up the orignal IE-based Remote console window from Chrome, (by leaving the *Open pop-up windows with Chrome* unchecked)

**NOTE:** The upper steps worked fine Windows 7, with IE11 installed; I've not tested it on other setups.